# How to properly specify the type of a local array in Numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, numba

I have a local array declared in a cuda-compiled numba kernel:

```
from numba import cuda, types

@cuda.jit((types.void(), device=True)
def A():
    arr = cuda.local.array(30, dtype=types.int64)
```

I need then to pass this array to another cuda compiled function:

```
@cuda.jit((types.void(), device=True)
def A():
    arr = cuda.local.array(30, dtype=types.int64)
    B(arr)

@cuda.jit((types.void(
  # What is the argument type?
), device=True)
def B(arr):
    # do things with arr
    pass
```

I tried typing like this:

```
@cuda.jit((types.void(
  types.Array(types.int64, 1, 'A')
)), device=True)

@cuda.jit((types.void(
  types.Array(types.Literal, 1, 'A')
)), device=True)

@cuda.jit((types.void(
  types.Array(types.Literal[int64](-1), 1, 'A')
)), device=True)

@cuda.jit((types.void(
  types.Array(types.Literal[int](-1), 1, 'A')
)), device=True)

@cuda.jit((types.void(
  types.Literal[int](-1)
)), device=True)
```

None of it works, I get various errors such as:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.core.typeinfer.ArgConstraint object at 0x7fb691c9d950>.
'property' object has no attribute 'is_precise'
During: typing of argument at /home/file.py (94)
Enable logging at debug level for details.
```

Or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/file.py", line 43, in <module>
    types.Array(types.Literal[int], 1, 'A'),
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: type 'Literal' is not subscriptable
```

Or

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function eq>) found for signature:
 
 >>> eq(array(int64, 1d, C), Literal[int](-1))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t necessary to do anything special when passing arrays with CUDA kernel specialised attribute (local or shared) to device functions, and the device function doesn’t need a special signature. Just use a signature with the correct dtypes and pass the array to the device function. The compiler will correctly handle the special attributes and generate code accordingly.

For example:

```
from numba import cuda, types

@cuda.jit(types.int64(types.int64,types.int64), device=True)
def cmpexch(x,y):

  if x > y: return x,y
  else: return y,x

@cuda.jit(types.void(types.int64[:]), device=True)
def sort4(arr):

    arr[2], arr[4] = cmpexch(arr[2], arr[4]);  
    arr[0], arr[1] = cmpexch(arr[0], arr[1]);
    arr[0], arr[2] = cmpexch(arr[0], arr[2]);  
    arr[1], arr[4] = cmpexch(arr[1], arr[4]);
    arr[2], arr[3] = cmpexch(arr[2], arr[3]);
    arr[1], arr[2] = cmpexch(arr[1], arr[2]);
    arr[2], arr[3] = cmpexch(arr[2], arr[3]);  
    arr[0], arr[1] = cmpexch(arr[0], arr[1]);
    arr[3], arr[4] = cmpexch(arr[3], arr[4]);


@cuda.jit(types.void(types.int64[:],types.int64[:], types.int64[:]))
def shufflesort_k(data, indices, output):

    larr = cuda.local.array(4, dtype=types.int64)
    idx = cuda.grid(1)
    
    larr[0] = data[indices[4*idx+0]]
    larr[1] = data[indices[4*idx+1]]
    larr[2] = data[indices[4*idx+2]]
    larr[3] = data[indices[4*idx+3]]

    sort4(larr)
    output[4*idx] = larr[0]
    output[4*idx+1] = larr[1] 
    output[4*idx+2] = larr[2]
    output[4*idx+3] = larr[3]

import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,2048, 128, dtype=np.int64)
irange = np.arange(0,128, dtype=np.int64); np.random.shuffle(irange)
res = np.zeros_like(data)

shufflesort_k[1,32](data, irange, res)

print(data[irange])
print(res)
```

Here we have a device function which can accept a local array as an argument, and another device function which can accept the elements of a local array as an argument. When called from a kernel, both compile and run correctly for me using Numba 0.56.4:

```
[1601  646 1537  588  440  825  744 1031 1595 2023  883   39  207  872
 1361  397   53  176  585  890   28 1379 1493 1392  864 1444 1779  736
 1074  240  588  558 1078  470  734 1306  591 1250 1370 1628   91  134
   67   10  518 1102  259  174 1264 1452   68 1842  366 1827   78 1806
  509  582 1504  325  501 1942 1833 1204 1678  416  372 2042  668  530
  237 1292  467  654 2004 1365   80 1721 1949  324  132  713 1351 1143
 1875  587 1635  725  685 1766  668  951  456 1543 1896 1443 1924  734
  961  578  805 1429 1127  674  424  943 1692 1160 1790  784 1360  540
 1724   16 1488  434 1780  627 1412 1355 1614 1909 1389  988 1902  194
 1936  506]
[1601 1537  646  588 1031  825  744  440 2023 1595  883   39 1361  872
  397  207  890  585  176   53 1493 1392 1379   28 1779 1444  864  736
 1074  588  558  240 1306 1078  734  470 1628 1370 1250  591  134   91
   67   10 1102  518  259  174 1842 1452 1264   68 1827 1806  366   78
 1504  582  509  325 1942 1833 1204  501 2042 1678  416  372 1292  668
  530  237 2004 1365  654  467 1949 1721  324   80 1351 1143  713  132
 1875 1635  725  587 1766  951  685  668 1896 1543 1443  456 1924  961
  734  578 1429 1127  805  674 1692 1160  943  424 1790 1360  784  540
 1724 1488  434   16 1780 1412 1355  627 1909 1614 1389  988 1936 1902
  506  194]
```